# Return an object response from a function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, callback, return-value, es6-promise

I am a little confused by the difference between asynchronous/synchronous. A little background, I am trying to write a program that is using callbacks and promises. I was trying to create nested requests, but the value of the object is not carrying through those requests, so I am creating a function that takes input a JS object, modifies it, and returns back the js object. The modification would include an API call that looks for another field to add to the JS object.

Can I accomplish this by something similar to this:

```
  TEST1 function(....){
        // do stuff
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
                  // do stuff to get js object
                  jsobject = objectModification(jsobject); //modified js object
       });
  }

  objectModification function(jsobject) {
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
                  // do stuff to modify js object
       });
        return jsobject;
  }
```

Comment: I think your function invoke should be... `jsobject = objectModification(response);`... if you use Promises, this could be much simplier...

Comment: Would this even work? It keeps returning "unidentified" when I use the function method I explained above

Comment: I cannot see what is the request that you are doing ... so if you get `undefined` it is because that is what you got from `request.get` call ... What is `request`?, what url are you hitting?. Code is missing key pieces to provide a more precise solution.

Comment: From my understanding request is updating the object fine, however the entire JS object is not passing from function 'objectmodification' to test1, it is losing it's value and changing to undefined

Comment: you cannot return the result from a callback function

Comment: so objectModification is the call back function here?

Comment: what is the `request` object? Can you provide the code where you define it? Does it return a promise? You speak about promises, but your code sample shows no use of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a callback function to `objectModification`, so the caller gets informed when the final version of `jsobject` is ready, and what it is:

```
function TEST1(....){
    var options = { ... };
    request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
        // do stuff to get js object, for example:
        jsobject = response;
        // modify jsobject asynchronously:
        objectModification(jsobject, function (jsobject) {
            // here we have the final version of jsobject.
        });
    });
}

function objectModification(jsobject, done) {
    var options = { ... };
    request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
        // do stuff to modify js object, for example:
        jsobject.newProperty = response;
        // Then call callback function to pass the modified js object        
        done(jsobject);
    });
}
```